# Compare part of stringdate in string to datetime in C#.NET using LinQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

Help me how to compare part of the string date in the string with the exact datetime in C#.NET using Linq or any easy way??

Example:

```
//  10/23/2013 03:43:56 PM
string fileImageName = "Picture_MIGA1_2013_10_23_15_43_56.png";
```

Comment: You can use DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: Can you show the way this string represent a DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` (among other things):

```
DateTime toCompare = new DateTime(2013, 10, 23, 15, 43, 56);
string fileImageName = "Picture_MIGA1_2013_10_23_15_43_56.png";
var tokens = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileImageName).Split('_');
// take last 6 because there are the datetime informations in the filename
var dateTokens = tokens.Skip(Math.Max(0, tokens.Length - 6)).Take(6).ToArray(); 
if (dateTokens.Length == 6)
{
    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(
        string.Join("_", dateTokens),
        "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out dt);
    bool isSame = toCompare == dt;  // true
}
```

**Edit**

> How can i write with LinQ query

You haven't mentioned what type of cllection you have. So i show an example with a `List<string>`, for the sake of simplicity with your single string:

```
var fileNames = new List<string>() { "Picture_MIGA1_2013_10_23_15_43_56.png" };
List<string> allMatching = fileNames
.Where(fn =>
{
    var tokens = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split('_');
    var dateTokens = tokens.Skip(Math.Max(0, tokens.Length - 6)).Take(6).ToArray();
    if (dateTokens.Length == 6)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(
            string.Join("_", dateTokens),
            "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dt);
        return toCompare == dt;
    }
    return false;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: How can i write with LinQ query